# Configure SSL in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When I run `elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token` for create the token on my cluster configuration and I am getting the following error

```
ERROR: Unable to create an enrollment token. Elasticsearch node HTTP layer SSL configuration is not configured with a keystore, with exit code 73
```

I had configured my SSL configuration using `elasticsearch-certutil` which is a self sign cert and specify the following in my `elasticsearch.yml`. Here are my yml file content on ssl part :

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
```

but unlucky the issue seem like still remain as I cant generate the enrollment token. Even I try added new pieces of variables into my existing yml file, it also not solving the issue .
 Here are the new pieces of variables that I added in

```
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled:true 
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.type: PKCS12
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path:elastic-certificates.p12 <br><br>
```

After I added the new pieces of vairables, it shown me the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsException: Failed to load settings from [elasticsearch.yml]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromStream(Settings.java:1249)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.InternalSettingsPreparer.loadConfigWithSubstitutions(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:126)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:52)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.createEnv(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:110)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher.main(CliToolLauncher.java:64)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.xcontent.XContentParseException: [87:71] while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 89, column 1:
    xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: ...
    ^
could not find expected ':'
 in 'reader', line 90, column 1:
    xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore ...
    ^

 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 87, column: 71]
        at org.elasticsearch.xcontent.provider.json.JsonXContentParser.newXContentParseException(JsonXContentParser.java:52)  <br><br>
```

May I know what is the different between transport SSL and HTTP SSL ? From what I understood is transport SSL will used between the communication among the elasticsearch node in the cluster. Meanwhile, http SSL will used by external application such Kibana or your customized application.That's the reason why the error message during my enrollment token had confused me